# How can we implement timer while receiving data in socket programing in c

Tags: c, linux, sockets, timer

I have gone through the different questions, which were asked related to timer. And it seams my code should work. But it is not working when timeout occur while receiving the data on a socket. I have a made a function called timeout_timer and the definition of the function as follows:

```
timeout_timer(long seconds, long micro_seconds)
{
    struct itimerval *alarm_set;

    if (micro_seconds >= MILLION) {
        seconds = seconds + micro_seconds / MILLION;
        micro_seconds = micro_seconds % MILLION;
    }

    alarm_set = malloc(sizeof (struct itimerval));

    alarm_set->it_value.tv_sec = seconds;
    alarm_set->it_value.tv_usec = micro_seconds;

    alarm_set->it_interval.tv_sec = (seconds == 0 && micro_seconds == 0) ? 0 : 2;
    alarm_set->it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, alarm_set, (struct itimerval *) NULL) == -1) {
        pause();
    }
    free(alarm_set);
}
```

I have called this timeout_timer function as follows:

```
timeout_timer(3,0);

memset(rcv_msg,0x0, MAX_MSG); 
if ((n = recv(sd, rcv_msg, MAX_MSG, 0)) <= 0) 
{
    timeout_timer(0,0);
    close(sd);
    break;  
}
else
{
    timeout_timer(0,0);
    trim_space(rcv_msg);
}
```

It works fine when data is received within timeout limit. but it stuck when timer expires.
Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Can't you use e.g. [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) with a timeout?

Comment: I can use select, but this part of the code works fine at other place.

Comment: "*... it stuck when timer expires.*": It gets stuck were? In the call to `revc()`???

Answer (score 1):

Use or implement your event loop, perhaps with [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or Gtk/Glib or Qt/QCore, or implement it with [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) and perhaps [timerfd_create(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) syscalls.

BTW, in a multi-threaded approach, you could have your main thread doing the event loop, and other threads doing other processing.

Comment: I think it is a different concept. I don't want to change my concept.

Comment: If you don't want any kind of event loop, then you probably won't be able to satisfy reliably (and simply) your goals.

Answer (score 1):

What does your SIGALRM signal handler look like?

An empty body is fine, but you need a real handler, installed *without*  the `SA_RESTART` flag; otherwise the signal delivery does not interrupt blocking I/O functions.

Since the signal may arrive at a point when there is already some data available (just not *all* expected), the interrupted I/O function may return a short count. This may be difficult to detect, so it is best to have the timeout interrupt repeat (very soon, say every ten milliseconds). When your code notices it has been interrupted, you should explicitly disarm the timer, to stop the repeating interrupt.

I would personally also use a global `volatile sig_atomic_t keep_running;` flag, which is set to nonzero when setting the timeout, and cleared by the signal handler.